# Use config and wildcards in snakemake rule output

Tags: python, pipeline, wildcard, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have a list of fasta may be used, but some of them may also not be used, so I hope to use snakemake to index fastq if need

I bulit a yaml file like this

```
# config.yaml
reference_genome:
 fa1: "path/to/genome"
 fa2: "..."
 fa3: "..."
...
```

and I write a snakemake like this

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
rule all:
    input:
        expand('{reference_genome}.{type}', reference_genome=['fa1', 'fa2', 'fa3'], type=['amb', 'ann', 'pac'])
rule index: 
    input: 
        #reference_genomeFile
        ref_genome=lambda wildcards:config['reference_genome'][wildcards.reference_genome]
    output: 
        expand('{reference_genome}.{type}', reference_genome={reference_genome}, type=['amb', 'ann', 'pac'])
    log: 
        'log/rule_index_{reference_genome}.log'
    shell: 
        "bwa index -a bwtsw {input.ref_genome} > {log} 2>&1"
```

I hope snakemake can monitor the index file `(amb, ann, pac)`, but this script will raise follow error:

```
name 'reference_genome' is not defined
  File "/public/...", line ..., in <module>
```

update: base on @dariober's answer:
if we runing with following config.yaml

```
reference_genome:
 fa1: "genome_1.fa"
 fa2: "genome_2.fa"
 fa3: "genome_3.fa"
```

I expect the output is

```
genome_1.fa.{amb, ann, pac}
genome_2.fa.{amb, ann, pac}
genome_3.fa.{amb, ann, pac}
```

If we use following workaround

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand('{reference_genome}.{type}', reference_genome=['fa1', 'fa2', 'fa3'], type=['amb', 'ann', 'pac'])

rule index: 
    input: 
        #reference_genomeFile
        ref_genome=lambda wildcards:config['reference_genome'][wildcards.reference_genome]
    output: 
        expand('{{reference_genome}}.{type}', type=['amb', 'ann', 'pac'])
    log: 
        'log/rule_index_{reference_genome}.log'
    shell: 
        "bwa index -a bwtsw {input.ref_genome} > {log} 2>&1"
```

we will get

```
$ snakemake -s snakemake_test.smk --configfile config.yaml
```

```
# for reference_name is fa1
[Fri Dec  2 17:56:29 2022]
rule index:
    input: genome_1.fa
    output: fa1.amb, fa1.ann, fa1.pac
    log: log/rule_index_fa1.log
    jobid: 1
    wildcards: reference_genome=fa1
...
```

Thats not my expected output

the output is fa1.amb, fa1.ann, fa1.pac, but I wanted output is genome_1.fa.amb, genome_1.fa.ann, genome_1.fa.pac

Comment: Three questions: 1. Is the `rule index` supposed to run for each genome and filetype once, i.e. once for `fa1.amb`, `fa1.ann`, ... , `fa3.pac`? Or is the rule meant to use all 9 combinations of genome and genome type at the same time? 2. Aren't you missing an `{output}` in the `shell` part of your rule? 3. By `yaml` file that you build you mean a `configfile` which you also import into your `Snakefile`?

Comment: @euronion Hi, q1: No, if you run `bwa index -a bwtsw` one time, it will generate all three index file  `ie. fa1.{amb, ann, pac}` for one input genome. q2: No, this comand will output file with input_path.{amb, ann, pac} default, it not have `stdout`. q3: yes, I import it

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand('{reference_genome}.{type}', reference_genome=['fa1', 'fa2', 'fa3'], type=['amb', 'ann', 'pac'])

rule index: 
    input: 
        #reference_genomeFile
        ref_genome=lambda wildcards:config['reference_genome'][wildcards.reference_genome]
    output: 
        expand('{{reference_genome}}.{type}', type=['amb', 'ann', 'pac'])
    log: 
        'log/rule_index_{reference_genome}.log'
    shell: 
        "bwa index -a bwtsw {input.ref_genome} > {log} 2>&1"
```

```
snakemake -p -n -j 1 --configfile config.yaml
```

That is: Run rule `index` for each genome file, i.e., three times here. Each run of `index` generates the three index files. Note the use of double curly braces `{{reference_genome}}` to tell `expand` that this wildcard does not need to be expanded.

---

Example config.yaml:

```
reference_genome:
 fa1: "genome_1.fa"
 fa2: "genome_2.fa"
 fa3: "genome_3.fa"
```

Comment: Sorry, it's a little confusing here, you got my intention right, but the wildcards `reference_genome` is reference_genome name like `fa1, fa2, fa3`, it need be convert to a file path by `config['reference_genome'][{reference_genome}]`, but Its not work.

Comment: The script I posted works for me at least in `--dry-run/-n` mode. Try to show more details about the error and how you execute snakemake. Make sure you use `--configfile config.yaml`

Comment: yeah it can runing well in  dry run mode, however, the rule expect output is `fq1.{amb, ann, pac}, fq2.{amb, ann, pac}, fq3.{amb, ann, pac}`, not `genome_1.fa.{amb, ann, pac}, genome_2.fa.{amb, ann, pac} and genome_3.fa.{amb, ann, pac}`, you can check it using `"echo {output}"` instead of  `bwa index -a bwtsw {input.ref_genome} > {log} 2>&1` and `touch genome_{1, 2, 3}.fa` and then run `snakemake -j 1 --configfile config.yaml`

Comment: Here is a subset of output `[Fri Dec  2 17:56:29 2022]
rule index:
    input: genome_1.fa
    output: fa1.amb, fa1.ann, fa1.pac
    log: log/rule_index_fa1.log
    jobid: 1
    wildcards: reference_genome=fa1`

Comment: the rule expect output in this situation is `fq1.{amb, ann, pac}, fq2.{amb, ann, pac}, fq3.{amb, ann, pac}`, not `genome_1.fa.{amb, ann, pac}, genome_2.fa.{amb, ann, pac} and genome_3.fa.{amb, ann, pac}`, but I want latter as output

Comment: That's not what I get. With input `genome_3.fa` I get in output: `fa3.amb fa3.ann fa3.pac`. Edit your question with the output of your run, with or without `--dryrun` mode.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to get `genome_3.fa.amb genome_3.fa.ann genome_3.fa.pac` as output with input `genome_3.fa`

Comment: I have update it

Answer (score 1):

Building upon [dariober's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74653048/11318472) and judging from your comments, I think this is what you are looking for?

```py
configfile: "config.yaml"


rule all:
    input:
        expand(
            "{reference_genome}.{type}",
            reference_genome=list(config["reference_genome"].values()),
            type=["amb", "ann", "pac"],
        ),


rule index:
    input:
        #reference_genomeFile
        ref_genome="{reference_genome}",
    output:
        expand("{{reference_genome}}.{type}", type=["amb", "ann", "pac"]),
    log:
        "log/rule_index_{reference_genome}.log",
    shell:
        "bwa index -a bwtsw {input.ref_genome} > {log} 2>&1"
```

with `config.yaml`

```
reference_genome:
 fa1: "path/to/genome1"
 fa2: "path/to/genome2"
 fa3: "path/to/genome3"
```

I've modified the `rule all` to use the filepaths from `config.yaml` rather than the list `['fa1','fa2','fa3']`. I've also removed the `lambda wildcard` from the input of `rule index` as it seems unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a workaround, but this need use `reference_genome path` instead of `reference_genome name`, I can add a input rule in `rule all` to make sure the `rule index` been done. I think this will work although it will index all fasta I have. But in fact, I was using `reference_genome` as `refernce_genome name` in complete script，and  `reference_genome` can be update by other rule， so that I can only index the fasta I need.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You have to specify either the path or the information, which paths to select from the `configfile` somewhere.
Do you want to restrict the files `rule all` is called on? If yes, you use a list comprehension like `[v for k,v in config["reference_genome"].items() if k in ["fa1", "fa2", "fa3"]]` instead of the `list(config["reference_genome"].values())`.

Comment: Simply put I have many files that **may** need to be indexed, I have a list of all these files in the "reference_genome" in the config.yaml file. But not all of them need to be indexed, in case the rule is not running, I didn't know which files needed to be indexed. when the rules is running some other rules will pass a reference_genome name (your can assume this name is in a filtered fasta list provide by other rule) as {reference_genome}, so that we can get the path of the file from config['reference_genome'][{reference_genome}], then index.